# Boostrap 3 brand logo goes hidden in nav bar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This simple thing is frustrating me for hours. I have a simple navigation bar which has a brand logo. But the logo disappears sometimes(still loaded but hidden below) from the navigation bar.

HTML:

```
<nav class="header_blue navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>        
          <div class="navbar-inner">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
                <img id="my_img" style="display:block !important;" src="img/logo_img.png" alt="logo_img" class="img-responsive">
           </a>
          </div>        
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            </ul>
             <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-hide="currentUserSignedIn">
                 <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="" id="signup_btn">Register</a> 
                    </li>

                     <li>
                        <a href="" id="sign_in" data-target="login_modal" >Sign In</a> 
                    </li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></nav>
```

CSS:

```
.header_blue{
background:none repeat scroll 0% 0% #073648;}
```

Comment: any screen short of disappearing logo?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jv60nqu8/. I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: yes I too cant reproduce it. Whenever the image disappears, the image is hidden behind the navbar. when i click the image it appears back. It also appears when i enable developer options in the browser.

Comment: I have added a default height and width in the image tag, now it seems to work fine. Removing them has the same issue. I don't know exactly how it works.